# How to calculate the time difference in SQL with DATEDIFF?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, datediff

I am using the `DATEDIFF` function to calculate the difference between my two timestamps.

```
payment_time = 2021-10-29 07:06:32.097332
trigger_time = 2021-10-10 14:11:13
```

What I have written is : `date_diff('minute',payment_time,trigger_time) <= 15`
I basically want the count of users who paid within 15 mins of the triggered time
thus I have also done `count(s.user_id) as count`
However it returns count as 1 even in the above case `since the minutes are within 15` but the dates 10th October and 29th October are 19 days apart  and hence it should return 0 or not count this row in my query.

How do I compare the dates in my both columns and then count users who have paid within 15 mins?

Comment: Not in Postgres unless you have created your own version of `datediff`.  It does not exist in Postgres as a built in function.

Answer (score 1):

This also works to calculate minutes between to timestamps (it first finds the interval (subtraction), and then converts that to seconds (extracting EPOCH), and divides by 60:

```
 extract(epoch from (payment_time-trigger_time))/60
```

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL, I prefer to subtract the two timestamps from each other, and extract the epoch from the resulting interval:

Like here:

```
WITH                                                                                                                                                 
indata(payment_time,trigger_time) AS (
          SELECT TIMESTAMP '2021-10-29 07:06:32.097332',TIMESTAMP '2021-10-10 14:11:13'
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2021-10-29 00:00:14'       ,TIMESTAMP '2021-10-29 00:00:00'
)
SELECT 
  EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM payment_time-trigger_time) AS epdiff 
, (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM payment_time-trigger_time) <= 15) AS filter_matches
FROM indata;
-- out      epdiff     | filter_matches 
-- out ----------------+----------------
-- out  1616119.097332 | false
-- out       14.000000 | true
```